# Can music be played simultaneously on Homepod and another device using the same account?

Tags: apple-music, homepod

When signed in with an Apple Music account on Homepod and another device, can I play music on both devices simultaneously? I believe it's not possible for e.g. iTunes and an iPhone; is Homepod an exception?

Specifically, it would be quite annoying if a family member at home started to play music and this disqualified me from listening on my iPhone on the go.

Answer (score 1):

You can definitely listen to Apple Music on multiple devices simultaneously.

(In fact, my Homepod, Apple TV, and iPhone have an annoying propensity for *all* trying to play songs at the same time, instead of controlling one-another.)